# Significance of the Light Effect in the film Aparichit during his transitions

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, anniyan

I recently revisited the Indian movie *Anniyan* aka *Aparichitudu*, and 'Aparichit' to Telugu and Hindi viewers respectively. The film presents a compelling protagonist, Ramanujam, who grapples with multiple personality disorder. One particular element that caught my attention was a distinct visual effect that materializes whenever Ramanujam transitions between his personalities.

This visual element, a light seemingly traversing Ramanujam's body [1](https://youtu.be/dDty4ER5ZGI?t=1179) [2](https://youtu.be/dDty4ER5ZGI?t=3758) [3](https://youtu.be/dDty4ER5ZGI?t=7962), appears to serve as a symbolic representation of the transformative process occurring within him during these personality shifts, especially from Ramanujam to Aparichitudu. Consistently featured throughout the narrative, this 'light effect' becomes a significant aspect of the film's storytelling approach.

The possible symbolic hint of this light could be that it represents the significant internal shift within the character during his personality changes. The trajectory of the light, moving from the base of the spine to the head, might also be a visual metaphor for the awakening of Kundalini, a concept prevalent in yogic philosophy.

If anyone has information on whether this visual effect was intentionally designed to represent this or another concept, or if there are any interviews or behind-the-scenes material that discuss the rationale behind this effect, it would contribute to understanding its role in the film.

Comment: Please write a comment if possible on how the question is an opinion-based.

Comment: I really don't see how it is. I reopened it accordingly.